# LDAP Unsolicited Notification using spring

Tags: java, spring, security, ldap, spring-ldap

Sorry if I don't get the exact phrases here, I'm pretty new to this area...

I'm using Spring LDAP to authenticate/validate users. I want to be able to get notification sfrom LDAP once there have been changes like removing or updating users.

I know I can have something like a scheduled task that will run and will check the specific users or groups i'm interested in, but I'm looking for something that gives me unsolicited notifications.

I looked online and found the following:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/ldap/unsol.html
and this looks promising, but i don't understand how to use it, plus I don't think spring really supports it and that i'll have to use the jndi classes, like in the attached link.

Also, it looks like the only notifications I will get are Notice of disconnection: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511#section-4.4 is that true?

And finally, I used the sample code I found, but I didn't get any notification from my AD server, is it because I'll only get notification about disconnection, or is there a setting i need to set in AD to enable these notifications?

Here is the sample code. I tried several DNs for the lookup and the `ctx.addNamingListener`, but maybe someone has a better idea for what I need to use there.

```
class RegUnsol {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Set up environment for creating initial context
    Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>(11);
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://MY_AD_IP");

    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,
            "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=sanity,DC=local");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "SOME_PASSWORD");

    try {
        // Get event context for registering listener
        EventContext ctx = new InitialContext(env)
                .lookup("CN=Users,DC=sanity,DC=local");

        // Create listener
        NamingListener listener = new UnsolListener();

        // Register listener with context (all targets equivalent)
        ctx.addNamingListener("CN=Users,DC=sanity,DC=local",
                EventContext.ONELEVEL_SCOPE, listener);

        // Wait 1 minutes for listener to receive events
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(60000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("sleep interrupted");
        }

        // Not strictly necessary if we're going to close context anyhow
        ctx.removeNamingListener(listener);

        // Close context when we're done
        ctx.close();

    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * A sample UnsolicitedNotificationListener.
 */
static class UnsolListener implements UnsolicitedNotificationListener {
    @Override
    public void notificationReceived(UnsolicitedNotificationEvent evt) {
        System.out.println("received: " + evt);
    }

    @Override
    public void namingExceptionThrown(NamingExceptionEvent evt) {
        System.out.println(">>> UnsolListener got an exception");
        evt.getException().printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I believe AD is pretty non-standard when it comes to LDAP, so that may be a source of trouble. From http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2251.txt it definitely looks like disconnect is the only standard notification. You may want to look at Persistent Search and Entry Change Notification Controls in https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/docs/getting-started/controls.php

Comment: When you update a user, LDAP modify, you get a response that is was successful. What else are you looking for?  All changes? Look at the DirSync Control. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677626(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @jeemster I will not be updating users, i want to know if someone is updating or deleting users or groups in the LDAP server itself.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers. As i said, i'm not going to be using UnboundID, but i will try using the persistent search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe unsolicited notification will not help you. (AFAIK, the only notification any server implements is a notice of disconnection)

You could implement a [persistent search](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/Persistent%20Search%20Control) if you need the information in realtime.

Or you could query, periodically, to see who got changed and by whom.

Either method, you would look at modifiedTimeStamp and modifierName.

I found a [JNDI implementation](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1157474?start=0&tstart=0).

Answer (score 0):

Just add a JNDI NamingListener. Sample code for that is provided in the [package documentation for javax.naming.event](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/event/package-summary.html).

Comment: the sample code doesn't work. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428235/operationnotsupportedexception-in-naming-listener) has the same problem i'm seeing.

Answer (score 0):

The `UnsolicitedNotification` is sent by servers to connected clients when an event transpires that requires clients to be notified, for example, the client is going to be disconnected.

Your client requires **change notification**. A change notification is dependent on the server in use. Many professional-quality servers support the **[persistent search](http://ldapmaven.com/2011/10/13/mastering-persistent-search/)** for this purpose. The link describes the persistent search and provides a complete example of its use using the **[UnboundID LDAP SDK](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/index.html)**.

Alternatively, many servers support the notion of a `change log`. The legacy Sun DSEE server supports this notion by the name of the `retro change log`. The **[UnboundID Directory Server](https://www.unboundid.com/products/identity-data-store.php)** also supports a change log (as well as change notifications by other means).